# How to get mac address using GCDAsynUdpSocket

Tags: ios, mac-address, gcdasyncsocket

I am using GCDAyncSocket for UDP broadcast. I receive the data in the form of NSData. How can I get the mac address from that received data? I tried with

NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

But it shows the msg as nil.

How can I get the MAC address from this received data?
I would appreciate your help.